# DATEDIFF (in months) in linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
select col1,col2,col3 from table1 
where(DATEDIFF(mm, tblAccount.[State Change Date], GETDATE()) <= 4
```

I want to convert this sql query to LINQ. but I dont know any DateDiff alternative in LINQ. can you please suggest me?

Answer (score 13):

You're looking for [`SqlMethods.DateDiffMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.datediffmonth.aspx).

**EDIT**: In EF4, use [`SqlFunctions.DateDiff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466401.aspx).

Comment: I am sorry I am using Entity framework not linq to sql. How can I do it using linq ?

Comment: Then why did you use the LINQ to SQL tag?

Comment: Entity Functions/Canonical Functions are another and perhaps better option in EF4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx . I believe the `SqlFunctions` are dependent on using SQL Server as data provider, `Entity Functions` are not. If I understand the description on MSDN correctly...

Comment: @SLanks: I used this function in above query but it gives :The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: Presently in EF6, use `DbFunctions.<various date methods>`.

Answer (score 9):

Putting aside your original question for a moment, in your query you use:

```
where(DATEDIFF(mm, tblAccount.[State Change Date], GETDATE()) <= 4
```

This query would always cause a full table scan, since you're comparing the result of a function call against a constant. It would be much better if you calculate your date first, then compare your column value against the calculated value, which would allow SQL to use an index to find the results instead of having to evaluate every record in your table.

It looks like you're trying to retrieve anything within the past 4 months, so in your application code, try calculating the date that you can compare against first, and pass that value into your Linq2Entities expression:

```
DateTime earliestDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(-4);
var results = from t in context.table1
              where t.col3 >= earliestDate
              select t;
```

Comment: This is a much more actually helpful answer.

Answer (score 7):

In EF6, the class to use is [`DbFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). See, for example, [`DbFunctions.DiffMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffmonths(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in another manner: I calculated the date from code:

```
theDate = Date.Now.AddMonths(-4)
```

And in EF change the condition:

```
tblAccount.[State Change Date] < theDate
```